# Why does C++ compiler fail to compile when not using a const in a parameter?

Tags: c++, dictionary, max, constants

I am trying to return the max value of a `std::map`.

```
int main() {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    map<int,int > m;
    while(N--) {
        int x; cin >> x;
        m[x]++; 
    }
    cout << max_element(m.begin(), m.end(), pred)->first;
    return 0;
}
```

If I define `pred` like this, it works:

```
bool pred(const pair<int,int>& lhs, const pair<int,int>& rhs){
    return lhs.second < rhs.second;
}
```

Whereas, this does not work:

```
bool pred(pair<int,int>& lhs, pair<int,int>& rhs){
    return lhs.second < rhs.second;
}
```

I don't understand why `const` allows it to work.

Comment: Change the parameters to `pair<const int, int> &` and try again. The map key is, obviously, a `const`. You can't change the key of a particular value in the map, on the fly, obviously.

Comment: Yah but I am not trying to change anything. Why do I need the const?

Comment: you need the const because you cannot legally cast or convert away const in any part of the program. that's called const correctness, in C++ it's part of type-safety. if you try to pass const things to a function that takes non-const reference, it's a compilation error. const things cannot bind to non-const reference.

Comment: Did you get a compile-time error message? Please update your question to show the message.

Comment: Because the key in the map is a `const` value.

Answer (score 0):

The value type of `std::map<K, V>` is not `std::pair<K, V>` but rather `std::pair<K const, V>`: you cannot change the key of an element of the `std::map<K, V>`. You should use the correct value type for the arguments of your `pred()` function:

```
bool pred(std::pair<int const, int>& lhs, std::pair<int const, int>& rhs) { ... }
```

or, preferably

```
bool pred(std::map<int, int>::reference lhs, std::map<int, int>::reference rhs) { ... }
```

Your `pred()` function doesn't change the arguments. Correspondingly it can and probably should also take the arguments by `const&` as that allows the use of a `std::map<K, V> const`. However, when using the function only with a non-`const` map doing so isn't required assuming it uses the correct value type.

Since `std::pair` has a conversion operator from other `std::pair` types, it can [implicitly] convert from `std::pair<int const, int>` to `std::pair<int, int>`. However, the result is a temporary `std::pair<int, int>` which cannot be bound to a non-`const` reference. For a pair of `int` values there is probably no large performance difference but the implicit conversion can easily be a major performance problem, e.g., when the key or the value contains an container of some form.

Comment: Ok thank you. That was clear. Where else can these "implicit" conversions be seen in which it is necessary to use a `const` regardless whether I actually intend on changing the value.

Comment: @sbryan1: the `value_type` of the various associative containers is the most common case I'm aware of. There are probably other cases where `tuple`-like types contain a member which may not exactly match the type it is used with. For example, when assigning a `std::tuple<int&>` to a `std::tuple<int>` you'd get a similar conversion yielding a temporary.

BTW, the currency on Stackoverflow isn't "thanks" but accepting answers, possibly also voting them up if you think they are decent.